# Having issue with file path

Tags: java, android, path

I am successfully able to select file programmatically. But, when I am getting `uri` from that file

> content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3356
>
> content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/3331

Unfortunately, wherever the file is my `uri` is always locating at `downloads.documents`

I think it doesn't fact. Cause, everyone get the `uri` by `data.getData()`. So, I think the `uri` is correct.

Last year, I was working with `Audio, Video, File and Image` uploading to server. I was trying that source code to get `path`.

```
String mediaPath, mediaPath1;
String[] mediaColumns = {MediaStore.Video.Media._ID};
// Get the file from data
            String path = data.getStringExtra(mediaPath);
            File file = new File(path);
            Uri selectedFile = Uri.fromFile(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()));
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedFile, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            assert cursor != null;
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            txt.setText(path);
            // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
            cursor.close();
```

Unfortunately,That is returning null pointerexception. After researching little bit, I found another source code([PathUtils](https://github.com/Istiakshovon/PdfReader/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/pdfreader/PathUtils.java))

```
public class PathUtils {
public static String getPath(final Context context, final Uri uri) {

    // DocumentProvider
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && DocumentsContract.isDocumentUri(context, uri)) {

        if (isExternalStorageDocument(uri)) {// ExternalStorageProvider
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];
            String storageDefinition;


            if("primary".equalsIgnoreCase(type)){

                return Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + split[1];

            } else {

                if(Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()){
                    storageDefinition = "EXTERNAL_STORAGE";

                } else{
                    storageDefinition = "SECONDARY_STORAGE";
                }

                return System.getenv(storageDefinition) + "/" + split[1];
            }

        } else if (isDownloadsDocument(uri)) {// DownloadsProvider

            final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
                    Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id));

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, null, null);

        } else if (isMediaDocument(uri)) {// MediaProvider
            final String docId = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);
            final String[] split = docId.split(":");
            final String type = split[0];

            Uri contentUri = null;
            if ("image".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("video".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            } else if ("audio".equals(type)) {
                contentUri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
            }

            final String selection = "_id=?";
            final String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{
                    split[1]
            };

            return getDataColumn(context, contentUri, selection, selectionArgs);
        }

    } else if ("content".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {// MediaStore (and general)

        // Return the remote address
        if (isGooglePhotosUri(uri))
            return uri.getLastPathSegment();

        return getDataColumn(context, uri, null, null);

    } else if ("file".equalsIgnoreCase(uri.getScheme())) {// File
        return uri.getPath();
    }

    return null;
}

public static String getDataColumn(Context context, Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {

    Cursor cursor = null;
    final String column = "_data";
    final String[] projection = {
            column
    };

    try {
        cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            final int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
    } finally {
        if (cursor != null)
            cursor.close();
    }
    return null;
}


public static boolean isExternalStorageDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.externalstorage.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}


public static boolean isDownloadsDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.downloads.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isMediaDocument(Uri uri) {
    return "com.android.providers.media.documents".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}

public static boolean isGooglePhotosUri(Uri uri) {
    return "com.google.android.apps.photos.content".equals(uri.getAuthority());
}
}
```

I am not getting any error. But, `Path` is always locating at `Downloads` file. I don't know why. After looking at uri I noticed my uri is always returning `downloads.documents`. I am not sure is it the issue.

There is lot of question similar to this question in stackoverflow. To tell everyone none worked for me. So, I will request to not flag it.

> PATH: /storage/emulated/0/Download/The Road to Reality ( PDFDrive ).pdf
>
> PATH: /storage/emulated/0/Download/The order of time ( PDFDrive ).pdf
>
> PATH: /storage/emulated/0/Download/pdf_495.pdf

First pdf file is in `documents` file. Second pdf file is in `Download` third pdf file is in `/storage/emulated/0/`

I am parsing pdf texts. Here is my code

```
try {
                        String parsedText="";
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                        //Here you can see I need path to load the pdf file
                        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(PathUtils.getPathFromUri(getApplicationContext(),PathHolder));
                        int n = reader.getNumberOfPages();
                        for (int i = 10; i <n ; i++) {
                            parsedText   = parsedText+ PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(reader, i).trim()+"\n";
                            Log.d("for_loop", String.valueOf(i));
                            Log.d("PARSED_TEXT",parsedText+" ");
                        }
                        builder.append(parsedText);

                        reader.close();
                        runOnUiThread(() -> {
                            txt.setText(builder.toString());
                        });

                      //    System.out.println("TEXT FROM PDF : "+builder.toString());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        System.out.println(e);
                    }
```

As you can see I need `path` to load the pdf file. But, I have already told you I am having issue with `path`. So, if I wanna do something with `uri` than how can i do that cause, `path` required.

I tried another way to get the `path` also.

```
Uri PathHolder = data.getData();

            Cursor cursor = null;
            try {
                cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(PathHolder, new String[]{MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA}, null, null, null);
                if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    String fileName = cursor.getString(0);
                    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/" + fileName;
                    Log.d("PATH",path);
                    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(this, "null return", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.d("EXCEPTION_ERROR",e.toString());
            } finally {
                if (cursor != null)
                    cursor.close();
            }
```

Unfortunately, It's not working also.

Like we do for `audio`, `images` or, `videos`.

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA};

            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            assert cursor != null;
            cursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            mediaPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            str1.setText(mediaPath);
            // Set the Image in ImageView for Previewing the Media
            imgView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mediaPath));
            cursor.close();
```

Edited :

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

            try{
                InputStream in = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);


                BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
                for (String line; (line = r.readLine()) != null; ) {
                    total.append(line).append('\n');
                }

                String content = total.toString();
                Log.d("CONTENT",content);
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

The problem I am facing here is.

[image]

[image: image2]

As you can see the `catch` is returning `no such file or directory` found. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. Cause, I took the source code from somewhere else and it is first time I am working with `InputStream`. And, I think the problem is on I am unable to get the file by `uri`.

Catch exception is returning

```
no such file or directory
```

Edited :

```
Uri uri = data.getData();

            File file=new File(uri.toString());

            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);

            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0){
                out.write(buf,0,len);
            }
            out.close();
            inputStream.close();
```

Comment: `Unfortunately, wherever the file is my uri is always locating at downloads.documents` No. Not possible. The user of your app can select files frim other places.

Comment: Those get path functions are nonsense. What is your problem? You got nice uries. Use them. Dont try to convert to paths. Not needed. You can do all with the uries themselves.

Comment: @blackapps Nice to see you again. I think you have already commented earlier in my question. Anway, as you can see `path` is required for But, if it possible to do without path. Than, i request for your help

Comment: It is unclear which help you want. Also i have no idea what should happen with the selected file.

Comment: @blackapps I need help to get path. But, you said all those are way to get path are useless. So, do you have idea how to get path? If not than how can I use that `uri` to read that PDF?

Comment: You will not try to get a path. Just open an input stream for the uri to read the file.

Comment: @blackapps Please, check my edited question.

Comment: You cannot use readLine() or a StringBuilder to read a pdf file. They are for plain text.

Comment: `As you can see the catch is returning no such file or directory found.` Sorry, but i dont see that.

Comment: @blackapps Now, can you see the debug info?

Comment: No. Dont post images. Post all as text.

Comment: @blackapps Catch exception is returning

`no such file or directory`. Could you tell me why? I am sure that I have selected a file.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Android 10 using Scoped Storage is required. You cannot get absolute path of the file and work with file APIs with external Storage. **MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA** that is used to take absolute path is depracated. But with uri returned you can copy that file using inputStream to your app-specific directory and do what you want with that file. For more information please refer to this [article](https://www.raywenderlich.com/9577211-scoped-storage-in-android-10-getting-started).

For reading pdf as I said you can copy that file to your app-specific directory or use that uri like this [sample](https://github.com/android/storage-samples/blob/main/ActionOpenDocument/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/actionopendocument/ActionOpenDocumentFragment.kt).

Copying file from uri in kotlin:

```
val uri: Uri = data?.data ?: return
        val ins = context?.contentResolver?.openInputStream(uri)
        val file = File(context?.filesDir, "image.jpg")
        val fileOutputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
        ins?.copyTo(fileOutputStream)
        ins?.close()
        fileOutputStream.close()
        val absolutePath = file.absolutePath
        Log.d("AAA", absolutePath)
```

If you use java there is no copyTo function so use this function then you can use the file in Files directory in app-specific storage

```
private void copyInputStreamToFile( InputStream in, File file ) {
try {
    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
    int len;
    while((len=in.read(buf))>0){
        out.write(buf,0,len);
    }
    out.close();
    in.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

[Copied file in app-specific directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjClp.png)

This is log:
D/AAA: /data/user/0/com.example.pickerapp/files/image.jpg

Comment: I have updated my question. Could you please check it?

Comment: I have updated the answer also do you know kotlin language? @kaziAbid

Comment: I don't know kotlin language but, I understand any programming language what is happening ok I will try. FYI, I don't have `File`. I only have `uri. So, please implement how to convert it though.

Comment: I don't have that `File` So, how can I try that source code?

Comment: And, `catch exception` always returning `java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory`. I added what I tried

Comment: @kaziAbid using that uri open inputStream 

InputStream is = getContext().getContentResolver().openInutStream();
copyInputStreamToFile(is, new FileOutPutStream(new File(getContext().filesDir(), "file.extension"));

 and copy the contents of that stream to the file opened in your app-specific directory like I showed above

Comment: this should help

Comment: `EXCEPTION_ERROR: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No such file or directory`

Comment: @kaziAbid please see this sample project https://github.com/AbdulazizRasulbek/StorageSample
I showed how to copy in kotlin. One question When FileNotFoundException occurs?
while copying or reading it?